# a[2] = a[a.length] deletes 2 of array a

Tags: java, arrays

```
a[2] = a[a.length-1]
```

When I use the above code in Java, it deletes index 2 of array a. From the inteliJ debugger I can't see it anymore. It goes from a[1] to a[3] then a[4] etc

`a` is a generics array. If I code

```
a[2] = a[7]
```

where 7 is the a.length-1 then it copies the values as expected

Comment: There's no deleting of array indexes.

Comment: It doesn't delete anything. It just assings the last element of the array into the second one. Also, what's the question?

Comment: It puts the last element of the array `a` inside the index 2

Comment: It just deletes a[2]. I can see it in the inteliJ debugger

Comment: It overrides element on position 2.

Comment: Maybe you can explain us what's your understanding of the term "delete" in this context.

Comment: What you're telling us doesn't make any sense in the usual usage of the word "delete" or for the behavior of array operations. Put this before and after that assignment, and show us the results: `System.out.println(Array.toString(a));`

Comment: (This sounds like a problem in your debugger rather than in Java.)

Comment: That is a shallow copy, you'll need to make a deep copy.  If it's a primitive than just create a new one with the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

If a is array of objects, then it could invalidate the old a[2] but still it points to an object so it is not deleted. You need to assign to null to delete it really and even that does not guarantee a quick deletion, you need the garbage collection triggered. Even that does not guarantee that your data is really deleted from memory trace. Some other application needs to use that area for a calloc/new and clear the area(maybe not for a server).

InteliJ debugger must have been tracking for a constant indexing. When you give a variable indexing plus invalidating the old one, it failed. Just as C++'s auto vectorization fails for same thing. Sometimes debuggers have bugs too(and this is not rare at times)